# $q$-series for the number of rectangles in a square lattice

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, partitions, generating-functions

Given a partition $\lambda\vdash n$ of $n$, look at its Young diagram $Y_{\lambda}$. Let $a(\lambda)$ be the number of squares (of all sizes) in $Y_{\lambda}$. For example, if $n=4$ then $a(4)=4, a(3,1)=4, a(2,2)=5, a(2,1,1)=4$, and $a(1,1,1,1)=4$. So, we have a total of $4+4+5+4+4=21$ squares.

Together with Richard Stanley ([unpublished, Section 9](http://dauns01.math.tulane.edu/%7Etamdeberhan/conjectures.pdf)), we proved that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_n(q)\, x^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k^2}q^{\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}6}}
{\prod_{j=1}^k\left(1-x^j\,q^{\frac{j(j+1)}2}\right)^2}, \qquad \text{where} \qquad
F_n(q)=\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}q^{a(\lambda)}.$$

> **QUESTION.** Now, instead consider $b(\lambda)$ to be the number of **rectangles** in $Y_{\lambda}$. Can you provide a generating function for $G_n(q)=\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}q^{b(\lambda)}$?

Comment: We have $b(\lambda) = \sum_{(i,j) \in \lambda} i \cdot j$.

Comment: (Whereas by comparison $a(\lambda) = \sum_{(i,j)\in \lambda} \min(i,j)$.)

Comment: Both are correct. Also that $\frac{d}{dq}F_n(q)$ and $\frac{d}{dq}G_n(q)$ evaluated at $q=1$ equal the total number of squares (resp. rectangles) in all partitions of $n$.

Comment: It also suggests that looking at $H_n(q)=\sum_{\lambda\vdash n} q^{c(\lambda)}$ where $c(\lambda) = \sum_{(i,j)\in \lambda}i+j$ might be interesting...